# Proof that $x^2 -3y^2 = 1$ has infinite solutions. ( x and y are integers)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

I have to explain this to my brother who is in eighth grade and I would really love if you could tell this in simple terms (I'm no Maths guy).

Comment: Because of the Diophantine tag, I assume you want $x, y$ to be integers?

Comment: yes, sorry for the lack of clarity earlier

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_equation

Comment: I did see that page however I am unable to understand how all that text could help me :/... most of it went over my head

Comment: Note that a single solution reveals an infinite class. $[1]$ If $(x, y)$ is one, then so is $(x^2+3y^2, 2xy)$. $[2]$ Note that $(2, 1)$ is a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we want integer solutions, it is easily noted that $(2, 1)$ is a solution.  Further, if you have one solution $(u, v)$ to this equation (refer Pell equations link given above for more), we can generate another solution as $(2u+3v, u+2v)$.  For a check, see

$$(2u+3v)^2 - 3(u+2v)^2 = u^2-3v^2 = 1$$

Now as the successive terms we generate are strictly greater than the earlier ones, we can generate an infinite number of them!

Comment: Great. Strange to see an eighth grader tackling Pell eqn though!

Comment: Just for a side project, seems his teacher likes to challenge the kids... (she does ask them to ask for help at home)

Answer (score 1):

Take any $y$ you want, you can always find $x = \sqrt{1 + 3y^2}$ so that $x^2 - 3y^2 = 1$. Because you can choose an infinite amount of $x$ values, you can find an infinite amount of (different!) pairs.

Comment: The solutions are probably meant to be integer valued.